# Need old version of readline for activator?

Tags: macos, readline, typesafe-activator

I am on a Mac and have run `brew install typesafe-activator`. Then I tried it out by running `activator` and got the following message:

`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/bash
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5`

Sure enough, there is no `libreadline.6.dylib` at that location. I have version 7 instead. I have tried to find a way to install the old version, but no luck so far. In particular, `brew` doesn't seem to have old versions available. Is there a way around this? Either a way to install the old version of `readline` or a version of `activator` that supports the new `readline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making and installing `readline 6.3` from source. [Here's the link](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/). Just download `readline-6.3.tar.gz`, unzip it, navigate to the unzipped folder, and run

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently bash needs to be upgraded.

```
brew upgrade bash
```

Source: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/5799

I did the exact same as you, installing gnuplot, which then started causing these errors, which I guess are linked to the brew update that I did at the time and not gnuplot.